# Validating FirstName in a web application

Tags: validation, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I do not want to be too strict as there may be thousands of possible characters in a possible first name

Normal english alphabets, accented letters, non english letters, numbers(??), common punctuation synbols

e.g.

```
D'souza
D'Anza
M.D. Shah (dots and space)
Al-Rashid
Jatin "Tom" Shah
```

However, I do not want to except HTML tags, semicolons etc

Is there a list of such characters which is absolutely bad from a web application perspective

I can then use RegEx to blacklist these characters

**Background on my application**

It is a Java Servlet-JSP based web app.
Tomcat on Linux with MySQL (and sometimes MongoDB) as a backend

**What I have tried so far**

```
String regex = "[^<>~@#$%;]*";
if(!fname.matches(regex))
    throw new InputValidationException("Invalid FirstName")
```

My question is more on the design than coding ... I am looking for a exhaustive (well to a good degree of exhaustiveness) list of characters that I should blacklist

Comment: What language? What platform? "web application" is pretty meaningless without more context.

Comment: it is a Java(servlet - JSP) platform ... Tomcat on Linux using MySQL as a backend (occasionally using mongoDB)

Comment: Then use the tags. You have up to 5 of them, you know?

Comment: So, what have you tried already?

Comment: I use the following regex ... [^~@#$%<>;?]* ... and use str.matches(regex) to figure out if it contains blacklisted characters or not

Comment: Again, _edit_ the question and add detail to it.

Comment: edited to include the information ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach is to accept anything anyone wants to enter and then escape any problematic characters in the context where they might cause a problem.

For instance, there's no reason to prohibit people from using `<i>` in their names (although it might be highly unlikely that it's a legit name), and it only poses a potential problem (XSS) when you are generating HTML for your users. Similarly, disallowing quotes, semi-colons, etc. only make sense in other scenarios (SQL queries, etc.). If the rules are different in different places and you want to sanitize *input*, then you need all the rules in the same place (what about whitespace? Are you gong to create filenames including the user's first name? If so, maybe you'll have to add that to the blacklist).

Assume that you are going to get it wrong in at least one case: maybe there is something you haven't considered for your first implementation, so you go back and add the new item(s) to your blacklist. You still have users who have already registered with tainted data. So, you can either run through your entire database sanitizing the data (which could take a *very* ***very*** long time), or you can just do what you really have to do anyway: sanitize data as it is being presented for the current medium. That way, you only have to manage the sanitization at the relevant points (no need to protect HTML output from SQL injection attacks) *and* it will work for all your data, not just data you collect after you implement your blacklist.